# No puedo entrar a mi servidor Ruby en localhost

Tags: ruby

Vi un video para hacer un servidor simple. Cuando lo corro en consola el servidor corre, pero al entrar al `localhost:2000` me aparece el error:

> No se puede acceder a este sitio Se ha restablecido la conexión.
>
> Intenta:
>
> Comprobar la conexión.
>
> Comprobar el proxy y el firewall.
>
> Ejecución del Diagnóstico de red de Windows

¿Por qué pasa esto? Adjunto el código:

```
require 'socket' 


server = TCPServer.open(2000) 
port = server.addr
loop { 
    client = server.accept
    client.print("HOLA") 
    client.close # Disconnect from the client
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código, tal cual está, si funciona. Si en tu loop pones un `puts` que indique cuando está recibiendo un request de la siguiente forma:

```
loop { 
    client = server.accept
    puts "Recibiendo request: #{client.gets}"
    client.print("HOLA") 
    client.close # Disconnect from the client
}
```

verás que cuando accedes desde el browser, verás un:

```
Recibiendo request: GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Que indica el tipo de request que recibió, para este caso, una llamada `HTTP`.

Y es justo ahí donde está tu problema, porque sólo estás iniciando un servicio `TCP`, pero no para responder al protocolo `HTTP`, que es el tipo de llamada que generalmente hace un browser.
Por lo tanto, para que tu browser te muestre algo, deberías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
require 'socket' 

server = TCPServer.open(2000) 
loop do
  client = server.accept
  puts "Recibiendo request: #{client.gets}"
  # Definiendo la respuesta con anterioridad, ya que la necesitarás para definir
  # el encabezado de tu respuesta
  respuesta = "HOLA"

  # Lo primero a definir en una respuesta HTTP es el Content-Type y
  # Content-Length, para hacerle saber al cliente el tamaño de la respuesta y el
  # tipo de dato con el que se está respondiendo (para este caso, texto plano,
  # pero podría ser una imagen jpg, un documento pdf, etc.). 
  # Vale notar que HTTP es sensible a espacios en blanco, así que cada línea
  # debe terminar con CRLF (ej: "\r\n")
  client.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: #{respuesta.bytesize}\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n"

  # Luego se imprime una línea en blanco que separe el encabezado del cuerpo de
  # la respuesta, como es requerido por el protocolo
  client.print "\r\n"

  # Finalmente imprimes el cuerpo de la respuesta, que es "HOLA"
  client.print respuesta

  client.close # Te desconectas del cliente
end
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias , me sirvio mucho.
Abrazo